# Chained Select Boxes - Basic

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have built this page: http://excelwrestling.com/poola.php for an upcoming dual tournament.  I have most all of the data being pulled from my mySQL database, with just some sample data in there now.

I am looking to chain the select boxes, so when the user chooses TEAM 1 (at the top), then it will update all of the WRESTLER 1 select boxes with only names from that team.  Same thing for team 2.

Another part of this is, is when a person chooses WRESTLER 1 vs WRESTLER 2, I want those two names to fill in the WINNER field, so the user can choose between those two names only.

Anything you can explain to me, or code you could post would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the winner always the team with the highest score? If so why do you need a field to select the winner?  You already know who won by examining the score.

Comment: Can you show whats in the database?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  Here is a sample of my form code.  http://jsfiddle.net/gDMvU/

Comment: Basically, I have 150 wrestlers to choose from, but they are divided into teams.  To make it easier for the person entering the data, I figured I could make it so when they choose: TEAM 1, it updates all of the WRESTLER 1 fields with the names associated with that team in mySQL.  Same for team 2.  As for the winners, there will be wrestler 1 vs wrestler 2 and I want to be able to see the winner in my database.

Comment: I think you need to start by considering your data structure. Consider making your data structure more relational.  Use one table for each of wrestlers, teams, meet, match etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use special queries to get wrestlers from teams. Then use a while loop to update all the wrestlers on a team from an array. Then assign the array to special select index numbers from the database.  Can you show whats in the database? I need to know in order to help. Since I don't know whats in your database. I'll just guess how your database is organized. Say that your team drop down list is called team_select and that each wrestler in the wrestler table had a wrestler_id wrestler_name and a team_id.

You would do the following code

```
     $team_select = $_POST['team_select']

            $wrestler_query = "SELECT wrestler_name FROM wrestler WHERE team_id = " 
. $team_select;

            $query = mysqli_query($connection, $wrestler_query);
            //Repeat code from here... (see bottom)
            while( $team_select = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
            {
               echo '<option class="Select1" value="' . $team_select['wrestler_name'] . '">'</option>
            } 
        <?
          </select>

        <?php
        mysqli_data_seek($accounts,0);
     //..to here for other drop down lists (except give the different names of different drop down lists in the html.)
```

Also don't forget, the connection variable is the database access credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted some more info above.  Let me know if you need me to post any more code. I'm pretty much a newb so you'll have to bare with me!

Comment: Ah yes, Wrestler 1:

<select name="Name_1">

    <?php
$sql = "SELECT Team,Name FROM boudro ".
"ORDER BY Name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['Team']."\">".$row['Name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>

Comment: Sorry, that's messy.  But that's what I have for selecting names from the database.  Pretty much everything is Name_1, Weight_1, Team_1, etc.

Comment: Just so you know I am still typing my message.

Comment: Sure thing! Is there any Javascript/jQuery involved?

Comment: Well since I'm a newb I'm going to have to dive in to this and figure it all out, but it seems like you understand what I want.  From all the tutorials I did, they all needed jQuery or Javascript. I'm not sure though.  Regardless, I appreciate your help!